# Search elements and return the object that corresponds to it in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

My app search in an array of object by name. Now when i search i get the first object that correspond to the name, but the issue appear when i try to write the second name, i don't get anything, because when i search i search only by one word:

```js
  const search = selectedItems => {
    let arrayOfMatchedObjects = elements.filter(object => {
      return JSON.stringify(object)
        .toString()
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(selectedItems);
    });
    console.log(arrayOfMatchedObjects);
  };
  search(selectedItems.join(",").toLowerCase());
```

In the code above, i filter my array depending by the value from input, and when i have to value offcourse the new value will be composed  from to words that are not in the main array. So how to get here `console.log(arrayOfMatchedObjects);` every object that matches the every name from the select?

This is the link of my sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-sea-opq2o

Bellow are `elements`:

```js
export const elements = [
  {
    key: "1",
    name: "Mike",
    age: 32,
    address: "10 Downing Street"
  },
  {
    key: "2",
    name: "John",
    age: 42,
    address: "10 Downing Street"
  },
  {
    key: "23",
    name: "Jack",
    age: 42,
    address: "10 Downing Street"
  }
];
```

Comment: can you please update the sandbox it's not working right now.

Comment: @Pavan, check please

Comment: Still does not work. elements.js file is empty

Comment: @Pavan, solved, now it is works?

Comment: @Pavan, i don't know why i can't save the file. I inserted the array in the question

Comment: I fail to understand what you're trying to do with search function.
You want to get the selected elements right? Search function is anyway not writing to the state.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209825/discussion-between-pavan-and-asking).